# MagickWand lib: write to buffer instead of file

Tags: c, imagemagick

How can I write in a buffer (unsigned char*) with MagickWand?

Currently I generate an image and save it to file, but I need it in memory:

```
MagickNewImage( wand, 640, 480, p_wand );
MagickWriteImage( wand, "test.jpg" );
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, you can use [`MagickGetImageBlob`](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/magick-image_8c.html#a0a454207fbc084658f994b1c3579dda8) it seems.

Comment: According to the documentation, "MagickGetImageBlob() implements direct to memory image formats. It returns the image as a blob (a formatted "file" in memory) and its length, starting from the current position in the image sequence. Use MagickSetImageFormat() to set the format to write to the blob (GIF, JPEG, PNG, etc.)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation there is a function `MagickGetImageBlob` that returns `unsigned char *` which is seemingly what you are looking for. Its exact documentation is

> `MagickGetImageBlob()` implements direct to memory image formats. It returns the image as a blob (a formatted "file" in memory) and its length, starting from the current position in the image sequence. Use `MagickSetImageFormat()` to set the format to write to the blob (GIF, JPEG, PNG, etc.).

Note that this does require you to set the format using `MagickSetImageFormat`, but on the whole this seems to be the closest thing to what you are looking for.